# Win Phone 8 Json Serialization

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, serialization, windows-8

i want to serialize an object using Json.Net, but i have this exception:

> 'TaskHost.exe' (Gestito): caricato 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
>   Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'System.MethodAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'System.MethodAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   Eccezione first-chance di tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   Error getting value from 'username' on 'HelloWorld.MainPage+TestLogin'.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ReflectionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract

My method for serialize object:

```
Login login = new Login();
            login.username = txtUsername.Text;
            login.password = txtPassword.Password;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Username: " + login.username);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Password: " + login.password);

            try
            {
                String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Json per HttpRequest: " + json);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

And the Login class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Login
    {
        public String username { get; set; }
        public String password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What's this error? I follow the example on internet and i get this error. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the access on the class and write:

```
public class Login
```

That should solve your problem. Just in case, edit post and add full json text.

Comment: Thx!! It's my first app with c# :)